# ngif value is getting changed after dom has been rendered in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The angular digest lifecycle is completed and there was a condition written for a particular div in ngif which value is being set after 2 api calls which gets set to true condition after dom has rendered.How to render this dom to detect the change in angularjs?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As the bot mentioned, we will need a minimum example because there is a limitless number of causes that fit your brief description. All that can be recommended until more information is provided is to ensure you are not modifying the DOM from another event. I've seen scenarios where an app disables buttons on http calls, then indiscriminately re-enables all the buttons. In that example, it is bypassing the lifecycle where ngDisable is evaluated. In short, follow angularjs best practices.